# How to make seekbar not change its size when moving its box in android studio?

Tags: android, xml

I have this seekbar in the pictures. I want to have two seekbars so I need to make the box take half of the screen to leave place for the other seekbar, but when i change the width of the box, the height of the seekbar changes. I think it is because the seekbar is rotated -90 degrees.
Is there anything I can do?
[image]

[image]